# Установить нестандартное свойство через js

Tags: css3, css, javascript

Привет

Помогите на чистом js установить такое свойство:

```
    @keyframes 'move_left'{
        from {
            margin-left: 130px;
        }
        to {
            margin-left: 0px;
        }      
    }
```

Comment: А задать анимацию для класса, а потом на JS только присвоить нужный класс нужному елементу, не подойдет?

Comment: margin-left во from будет являться переменной. Напишите строку кода, которая устанавливает именно 130px?

Answer (score 1):

Пример для webkit:

```
<style>
@-webkit-keyframes move_left{from{margin-left:130px}to{margin-left:0px}}
.move_left{
    border: 1px red solid;
    height: 40px;
    margin-left: 130px;
    width: 200px;
    -webkit-animation-name:move_left;
    -webkit-animation-duration:4.2s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:1;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function:linear;
}
</style>
<!-- какой-то стиль -->

<div class="move_left">элемент</div>

<script>
var s = document.createElement('style'); // создаем новый тег style
var t = document.createTextNode('@-webkit-keyframes move_left{from{margin-left:130px}to{margin-left:260px}}'); // переопределяем свойство
s.appendChild(t);
document.body.appendChild(s); // добавляем его в body
</script>
```